# Split and Merge between cell arrays in a cell

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3x1 cell, Which contains 3 3d matrices in the form of longitude x latitude x time. 
I want to know how I can cut the first time step(:,:,1) from every cell (except first one) and paste it in the previous row?

[image: Screenshot]

so, in the end, I should have something like this:

```
81x69x8761 double
81x69x8760 double
81x69x8759 double
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a simple `for` loop

```
% Create some dummy 3D data
c = repmat( {rand(5,3,20)}, 3, 1 );
% Loop over the cell array from element 2
for r = 2:numel(c)
    % Copy the last slice from the current array into the previous one
    c{r-1} = cat( 3, c{r-1}, c{r}(:,:,end) );
    % Remove the last slice from the current array
    c{r}(:,:,end) = [];
end
```

Result:

[image: output]